# How to fix DatetimeIndex.union_many is deprecated warning in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have the following code:

```
import datetime, pytz
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal

today_date = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
start_date = datetime.date(today_date.year - 5, today_date.month, today_date.day)

end_date = datetime.date(today_date.year + 2, today_date.month, today_date.day + 5)

nyse_calender = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
nyse_business_days = nyse_calender.schedule(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
```

When I run this, I get the following warning:

```
 FutureWarning: DatetimeIndex.union_many is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use obj.union instead.   
  nyse_business_days = nyse_calender.schedule(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
```

How am I supposed to solve this problem? The warning doesn't really help to take an action..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [PR](https://github.com/rsheftel/pandas_market_calendars/issues/168) for `pandas_market_calendar` was merged a couple of days ago which fixes this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you be able to guide in a more concrete way what needs to be done to solve the issue? I run my application in a docker container where the pandas_market_calendar is installed each time the container runs. The problem is still there as of today.

Comment: In my particular case, I've got `pandas_market_calendar` installed locally through `poetry`, so I just copied in the files that were modified by the PR and that was it for me.  For your use case through docker, I'm afraid that's out of my wheelhouse.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I assume the problem should be solved when I install the latest but it is just not the case. Manually copying files from one place is not an option in my case.

Comment: Sounds like your container gets the module through `pypi` or the like.  You'll probably be waiting until the maintainer makes a new release available there.  You could probably open an issue on GitHub to see when the maintainer might be making a new release available that incorporates that PR.

Comment: Yes, I do use a base, which is "FROM python:3.8-slim-buster" but it does not include the pandas_market_calendar and it is installed with pip each time the container starts. So I am not sure if this is maintainer related...

Comment: It would be maintainer related.  `pip` retrieves remote images from `pypi`, so if it gets the latest, it would be getting `3.3` (as of today) according to https://pypi.org/project/pandas-market-calendars/

Comment: That explains it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, just saw this one when I am about to raising mine. Here I provide couple more details of my debugging:

```
pandas version 1.4.0

pandas_market_calendars version 3.3(it also happens on version3.2)
```

the warning comes from line:

```
    nyse_business_days = nyse_calender.schedule(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
```

I did a further debugging into `pandas_market_calendars`, it was actually from market_calendar.py line 514, which looks like:

```
        for market_time in market_times:
            temp = self.days_at_time(_all_days, market_time) # standard times
            if _adj_col:
                # mark here, according with Yunfei's debugging, it orients from here
                # create an array of special times
                special = self.special_dates(market_time, start_date, end_date, filter_holidays= False)
```

from my side, the inputs to the function are like:

```
market_time
'market_open'
start_date
Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00')
end_date
Timestamp('2021-07-25 00:00:00')
```

as the line 514 is actually running from loop, my console shows thousands of such 'futurewarning', crying for help

Answer (score 1):

As of the pandas 2.0 release on April 3rd, 2023, the `DatetimeIndex.union_many` function has been deprecated (for more details, please check [PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/45018)). Now you can use `DatetimeIndex.union` which has similar functionality.

### Example

Defining two `pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex` objects and do union operation as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
date_range_1 = pd.date_range(start='2023-09-01', end='2023-09-06', freq='D')
date_range_2 = pd.date_range(start='2023-09-04', end='2023-09-14', freq='D')
result = date_range_1.union(date_range_2)
result
```

Returns:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04',
               '2023-09-05', '2023-09-06', '2023-09-07', '2023-09-08',
               '2023-09-09', '2023-09-10', '2023-09-11', '2023-09-12',
               '2023-09-13', '2023-09-14'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

### Note:

`DatetimeIndex.union` method can be used to union only one `DatetimeIndex` at a time. The deprecated `union_many` function was designed to support the union of a list of `DatetimeIndex` objects.